# Inserting Data manually into table in AWS Redshift, sql workbench

Tags: amazon-redshift, sql-workbench-j

[image]
I am able to connect to redshift from SQL workbench and I am able to create a table but When I try to insert values into the table It throws me the below error.

[image]

Since I am using temp schema and the connectivity shows schema as public, is this still an issue even if my insert statement is
Insert into tempschema.temp_staging values

Answer (score 1):

Postgres (and thus Redshift which is based on an ancient version of Postgres) has a very strict transaction concept: either all statements work or none.

As soon as one statement in your transaction fails, the whole transaction needs to be rolled back.

So all you need to do is to issue a `ROLLBACK` command and you can continue. There is no need to restart SQL Workbench/J.

If you don't want to do that for every statement that throws an error, just enable autocommit in the connection profile:

> **7.3.5. Autocommit**
>
> This check box enables/disables the "auto commit" property for the connection. If autocommit is enabled, then each SQL statement is automatically committed on the DBMS. If this is disabled, any DML statement (UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, ...) has to be committed in order to make the change permanent. Some DBMS require a commit for DDL statements (CREATE TABLE, ...) as well. Please refer to the documentation of your DBMS.
>
> [Link to manual](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/profiles.html#profile-autocommit)

*I am part of SQL Workbench/J support*

Comment: @Adriaan I am not spamming. I am merely linking to the manual to explain how that option is enabled. But I can remove the link to the manual if that makes you happy. I was just trying to be helpful

Comment: links can stay, but ideally they are not essential to the answer. This is to prevent link rot (ie: so that if a link ever changes, the answer stays relevant). And then also you need to disclose that you are part of the organisation behind the link (if you are). I have edited your answer to include all this so you can see what SO is after. Thanks for contributing!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a temporary acquired lock.

1. Disconnect the workbench from the datasource
2. Restart the workbench
3. Reconnect to your datasource.

You'll be able to resume from here.